# TypeError: val.array is not a function at Object.bot.findMember / В чем проблема?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord-api, node-modules

Захостил дискорд бота, `discord.js/Node.JS` ([ссылка на гит](https://github.com/Nioxed/manager-base))

На тестовых дискорд серверах он функционирует нормально, а на основном сервере с более чем 1000 участников не может захватить (добавить/удалить в канале) пользователя.

**Лог ошибок:**

```
TypeError: val.array is not a function
    at Object.bot.findMember (/app/bot_modules/general/module.js:32:31)
    at /app/bot_modules/rooms/commands/add.js:36:28
```

**module.js: 32:31:**

```js
var val = guild.members.find(val => val.displayName.includes(userid));
if( val != null) { if(val.array().length == 1){ return val; } }
```

**add.js:36:28:**

```js
var mentions = message.mentions.members.array();
var mentionroles = message.mentions.roles.array();
var resolvables = message.cleanContent.split(" ");

//resolve flat names to fake mentions or explode
for(var i = 0; i < resolvables.length; i++){
    if(bot.findMember(resolvables[i], message.guild) != null){
        mentions.push(bot.findMember(resolvables[i], message.guild));
    }
}
```

В чем проблема? Почему она возникает только на крупном сервере?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Те, две строки замени на:

```js
const val = guild.members.find((val)=>(val.displayName.includes(userid)));
if(val && Array.isArray(val) && val.length === 1)return val;
```

И вообще, `console.log(val);` пользуй, чтобы знать что там внутри, ничего страшного не произойдет если ты получишь *методом научного тыка* условный `N` из уравнения `X * Y = N`, где `X` - твой код, а `N` - результат, и путем логики сообразишь как *найти* правильный `Y`

Comment: Вадим, благодарю за отзывчивость. Сделал как вы написали. Появилась новая ошибка: 
`SyntaxError: Identifier 'val' has already been declared
    at /app/bot_modules/rooms/commands/add.js:36:28`

Comment: @Странник написано что `val` уже существует, я же сказал заменить.. закомментируй 36 строку, или какая там `var val`...

Comment: Вадим, мои понятия не слабы, просто эти не совсем входит в круг моих понятий, поэтому я здесь как слепой котенок. Первый раз сделал как вы написали и удалил только 2 обозначенные строки, про другое не знал. Сейчас указали дополнительно, убрал еще сверху в `if(guild)` этот самый `var val`. **Тьфу, тьфу, тьфу - заработало**, надеюсь в дальнейшем не будет ошибок. **Очень признателен**, так как потратил много времени на то, чтобы разобраться самому. К слову `console.log(val)` у меня тоже не корректно работал, оказалось нужно включить спец. режим в DS, чтобы это корректно работало.

Comment: @Странник вадим не гневаеца) Не слепой котенок, а английский надо учить, если уж собираешься жыжнь связать с прогенхом... `console.log(typeof val, val[0]);`